# Why do I need to use curator but not zookeeper native API as distributed lock?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

Our project depends on distributed lock heavily. I know curator provides several kinds of locks. My question is, can I just use the creating node as a mutex ?

```
CuratorFramework zkClient = zookeeperConnectionProvider.getZkClientForJobDistributeLock();
            try {
                zkClient.create()
                        .creatingParentsIfNeeded()
                        .withMode(CreateMode.EPHEMERAL)
                        .forPath("/" + job.getIdentifier().jobNodeString());
                LOGGER.info(String.format("create node in zookeeper [%s]", job.getIdentifier().jobNodeString()));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.info(String.format("create job instance node in zookeeper failed [%s], reason [%s]",
                        job.getIdentifier().jobNodeString(),
                        e.getClass().getCanonicalName()));
                return NO_WORK;
            }
```

When the first process creates successfully, the second process gets the 
`NodeExistsException` exception. If this can not work, I want to know the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first objection against doing as you propose is that it's hard to read/understand the code, compare it to:

```
InterProcessSemaphoreMutex lock = new InterProcessSemaphoreMutex(client, path);
lock.acquire();
```

Another reason is that you usually use locks to block a thread until another one releases the lock so you can write code that looks like this:

```
//do normal work
...
lock.acquire();
//do critical single threaded work
...
lock.release();
//back to normal work
...
```

Which is by all means possible with your code, but here it's created for you.

---

There are a lot more reasons to use a already implemented lock instead of writing your own, but it mostly boils down to: 'Why reinvent the wheel?"

Comment: Thanks Petter. What I need is something like a mutex, but the failed process need not to wait until the succeed one release. I had thought a naming node in zookeeper will be ok, but I found it did not work at all. Finally I turn to InterProcessMutex. The reason for not using it at the beginning is that  I read some docs knowing it creates several nodes in zookeeper and the mimimum index will get the lock.

Comment: So I thought one node could be more effective. After that I did some experiments:  process A create a node in zookeeper and keep the connection, then process B delete the node, I get an NoNode exception. If process A disconnected from the zookeeper server, process B can delete it correctly( ps: the node type is CreateMode.Persistent). Is there some "Isolation" mechanism between different connections?

Comment: If you dont want to wait for the lock you can use:
    
    Boolean hasLock = lock.acquire(1 , TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

Im not sure if you can use 0, but this will only wait for the lock for 1 milisecond so it should not slow down your code to much.
Oh, and if 'hasLock' is false you didnt get the lock.